# How can I write a Chrome extension on a Chromebook?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-os, chromebook

Is there any viable development flow that lets me edit, then load, a Chrome extension with nothing more than a Chromebook?

Comment: There are source code editor apps in Chrome webstore, but maybe [the built-in devtools workspace feature](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow?hl=en) is okay for you.

Comment: Any text editor in the webstore will be fine, and loading happens on chrome://extensions

Answer (score 0):

I use [Caret](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/caret/fljalecfjciodhpcledpamjachpmelml) and [Puresolid IDE](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/puresolid-ide/ndhdjddnbbjnojdjbglbpenimlpnlpbl) for most of my development. Caret is great because you can "collapse" various code such as functions and objects, making editing much easier. Puresolid IDE is great because you can create a project from a variety of templates, it has auto complete, and code suggestion.
As for turning my project folder into a Chrome app/extension I use [Chrome Apps & Extensions Developer Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-apps-extensions-de/ohmmkhmmmpcnpikjeljgnaoabkaalbgc).

Comment: Thanks! Is there any good workflow to sync your code with a SCM system, e.g. does Puresolid support git?

Comment: Honestly, no, it doesn't. Puresolid doesn't even get updated anymore. None of the editors I've used get updated anymore. Though I have considered making my own editor but haven't decided if it would even be worth it or not. Sorry.